# Why do I get a "Too many open files" error message, when trying to save images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a `for` loop that saves an image at each iteration using `saveas(gcf,[%link,'.jpg'])` It works well at the beginning, but crashes and displays an error message like this:

> ??? Error using ==> print at 339 Cannot create output file '/20110301/20110301225100.jpg'
>
> Error in ==> saveas at 155
>
> Error in ==> TSI_forecast_display_cloud_decision at 153 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/cwchow/.matlab/R2010a/matlab.prf (Too many open files) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs.save(Prefs.java:295) at com.mathworks.services.Prefs$SavePrefsThread.run(Prefs.java:702)

I get a similar result if I use `print`. I guess MATLAB is not closing files properly resulting in too many open files. Can anyone tell me how to avoid this error?

**UPDATE:**

I tried both figure handle and `fclose('all')`. I even used `close all`, they do not work. I still get the same error. I checked the system limit, it's already 1024.

Answer (score 5):

Try calling `fclose('all')` after `saveas` (assuming you have no other open file handles), to make sure that `saveas` is closing the file handles properly.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are not closing each file after you have saved to it. In Java you would call close() when you are finished.

Answer (score 1):

One bug that will supposedly fixed in the upcoming release 2011b is as follows:

> Description: On some Linux systems,
>   based on the Linux OS descriptors
>   limit, normal use of MATLAB may
>   trigger the following errors:
>
> ```
> Too many files open.
> Unexpected error status flag encountered. Resetting to proper
> ```
>
> state. While some GUIs may continue to
>   work, the MATLAB command line will
>   consistently error. Workaround: Check
>   the Linux OS limits using the limit
>   command in the Linux shell:
>
> [hostname:/home/lusername]1 % limit
>   descriptors If the descriptors limit
>   is set to less than 1024, reset the
>   descriptors limit to 1024. This will
>   be shell dependent. In tcsh, using
>   this command in a startup file (like
>   .cshrc) would be appropriate: limit
>   descriptors 1024